# Why is the speed of a quantum particle defined as coefficient of $t$ over coefficient of $x$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, velocity, dispersion, phase-velocity

I’m currently studying quantum mechanics from *Introduction to Quantum Mechanics* by Griffiths. In his free particle section, he says that the speed of a particle is the coefficient of $t$ over the coefficient of $x$. Shouldn’t it be the coefficient of $x$ over the coefficient of $t$?

Comment: Did you square away their dimensions?

Answer (score 1):

The following may be a useful approach.

A simple traveling wave can be written as:

$$
y=\sin\left(kx-\omega t \right)
$$

We want to follow the position of the wave at a constant phase, $\phi$.  Let that phase=0 which leads to:

$$
\phi=kx - \omega t = 0
$$

$$
kx=\omega t
$$

$$
x=\frac{\omega}{k} t
$$

Then the velocity will be

$$
v=\dot{x}=\frac{\omega}{k}
$$

which is the ratio of the coefficient of $t$ over the coefficient of $x$.

I hope this helps.